# joining one table to one column in table2

Tags: sql

I am still learning SQL and wanted to query a table and needed your help. I have two tables.

```
Table1  
GR_ID   US_ID
1       51
1       52
1       53
2       51
2       54
2       55
3       51
3       52


Table2  
MEM_ID  MEM_Name
1       Name1
2       Name2
3       Name3
51      Name51
52      Name52
53      Name53
54      Name54
55      Name55
```

Result expecting, to display table1 but with the names associated with ID from Table2.

```
Result  
Group   Users
Name1   Name51
Name1   Name52
Name1   Name53
Name2   Name51
Name2   Name54
Name2   Name55
Name3   Name51
Name3   Name52
```

Comment: What have you already done and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: is this mySQL? or SQLserver?

Comment: Table 1 is your primary table and you can do two joins (or left joins) to Table 2 for the lookups. Would you give it a go?

Comment: Thank you for your Response... its SQLServer.  I tried with Inner join but since I am referencing to the same Table Table2 to get the names of GR_ID and US_ID...its giving me error.

Comment: @THB Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for both MySQL and SQL Server:

```
SELECT b.mem_name as groups,
       c.mem_name as users
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 as b
    ON b.mem_id = gr_id
JOIN Table2 as c
    ON c.mem_id = us_id
ORDER BY groups
```

Hope this helps!